# Pressing enter on "find a stackexchange site" should go to first listed site

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

At the moment in the new StackExchange top-bar, when you type a search term into stackexchange site search and press Enter, the page refreshes or something similar. I think it would be better if you actually went to the first listed site in the search.

For example, if I typed "statistic", this brings up cross validated, and if I press Enter I would like to go to cross validated.

[image]

Similarly, and perhaps this should be another suggestion, up and down cursor keys should move the selection to the list of sites, enabling you to for example, press down key twice and then enter to go to the second listed site.

It might also be better to have some specific visual indication that you have you the selection corresponds to the first hit (i.e., like the Facebook search box).

As a side point I realised after a bit that you can tab and enter, which arguably works fine, but it was not the keyboard interaction that I was expecting. So I still think supporting both modes of keyboard interaction might be good.

Comment: What if there are multiple matches?  Non-deterministic behaviors isn't what we'd want in a UI.  Tabbing to the first match to highlight it and hitting enter maybe?

Comment: So when you search for history and press enter, you are redirected to Genealogy & Family history instead of History. Maybe not the result you expected, so I think this is not good idea.

Comment: I guess the issue is that there are multiple conventions regarding how user interaction occurs for selection boxes among large lists. Some use tab, others use cursor to navigate through the list; some auto-select the first match, whereas others require you to actively choose.

Comment: @juniperi I think that's more useful than just refreshing the current page. But perhaps you've also highlighted an issue in how the sorting works for the search list. Presumably "history" should appear above "geneaology" for a "history" search.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim I agree, refreshing current page is not the result I expected to happen either.

Comment: I agree with this request. At the very least, [enter should not just refresh the page.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210079)

Comment: I agree with not refreshing the page, but automatically going to the first chosen site seems too unintuitive to me.

Comment: @AnnaLear Perhaps it would be intuitive if there was some visual indication like on facebook  (e.g., the first hit was surrounded by a different colour box) that could me moved with the cursor.

Comment: Refreshing the page has been fixed, we'll take a look at other behaviors.