# Pressing Enter should not refresh the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

Currently, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering a partial simply refreshes the page. This should not happen. If I have not selected a site, then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> should do nothing. If I wanted to refresh, I can simply press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image: [#212121 is the new RED]]

Comment: Related: [Pressing enter on “find a stackexchange site” should go to first listed site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210077/pressing-enter-on-find-a-stackexchange-site-should-go-to-first-listed-site)

Comment: @JoshC That beat mine by just 5 minutes. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that's bad.  Fixed in the next build.